# Can't connect Robo3T to Google Cloud Platform compute engine via SSH

Tags: mongodb, ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, robo3t

I can SSH into my instance from the terminal like this:

`ssh -i <path_to_private_key> <username>@<external_ip_address>`

But I can not connect Robo3T via an SSH tunnel, using the same credentials - I get the error:

`Resource temporarily unavailable. Authentication by key (/home/alex/.ssh/id_rsa) failed (Error -16). (Error #11)`

Has anyone managed this, and if so, how can I?

Comment: It seems to me the issue is caused by the key format as discussed in this [public thread](https://github.com/Studio3T/robomongo/issues/1590). You may find this page helpful.